# Clicking Android Notification

Tags: android, notifications

I am showing notifications on a android device in some of my application. Each time notification is fired, a bundle saves the value and then on the click of the notification a new activity opens with the id in the bundle.

Now here I am in a problem that when one notification comes with id :A and simultaneously  if the user gets the notification with id : B. Now it will cause the bundle value to - B. Now If any of the notification is clicked, then the page will be opened with the new notification value. This is the main problem that the id gets updated.

I require that on notification click right page should always open

sending notification

```
    connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {

            @Override
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Message message = (Message) packet;
                senderName = packet.getFrom();

                // new code
                mMessageItem = new MessageItemDataClass();
                mMessageItem.isSendMessage = false;
                mMessageItem.messageText = message.getBody();

                int alphaPOS = senderName.indexOf("@");
                String subSenderName = senderName.substring(0, alphaPOS);



                refinedID = refineFromjId(packet.getFrom());

                Random rand = new Random();
                int randNotificationVal = rand.nextInt(1000);
                String notificationID = ""+randNotificationVal;

                while(idMap.containsValue(notificationID)){

                    randNotificationVal = rand.nextInt(1000);
                    notificationID = ""+randNotificationVal;

                }


                if(!idMap.containsKey(refinedID)){

                    saveNotificationID(refinedID, notificationID);
                }

                if (UserChatActivity.checkPresence == true) {

                    if (packet.getFrom().equalsIgnoreCase(
                            refineFromjId(UserChatActivity.frienduserID)
                                    + "/Smack")) {

                        UserChatActivity.messages.add(mMessageItem);
                    } else {
                        notificationforChat(
                                subSenderName + ": " + message.getBody(),
                                packet.getFrom().toString(), Integer.parseInt(idMap.get(refinedID))
);
                    }
                } else {
                    notificationforChat(
                            subSenderName + ": " + message.getBody(), packet
                                    .getFrom().toString(),  Integer.parseInt(idMap.get(refinedID))
);

            }



public void notificationforChat(CharSequence message, String toJid,
            int notificationID) {

        int notificationCount = 1;
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        CharSequence tickerText = message;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
        //notification.number = notificationCount++;
        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        CharSequence contentTitle = "Chat";
        CharSequence contentText = message;
        Intent notificationIntentforChat = new Intent(this,
                UserChatActivity.class);
        notificationIntentforChat.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        notificationIntentforChat.putExtra("userNameVal", toJid);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntentforChat, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText,
                contentIntent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        mNotificationManager.notify(notificationID, notification);
    }
```

UserChatActivity where bundle is checked

```
try {
            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (bundle.getString("userNameVal") != null) {
                frienduserID = bundle.getString("userNameVal");         
                int index_of_Alpha = frienduserID.indexOf("@");
                String subID = frienduserID.substring(0, index_of_Alpha);
                mtvChatTitle.setText(subID);
                //System.out.println("TRY == "+frienduserID);
            }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            //System.out.println(""+frienduserID);
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i have find the solution,

Download this library and add your project,

https://github.com/JakeWharton/NotificationCompat2/downloads

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.example.notification.R.id;
import com.jakewharton.notificationcompat2.NotificationCompat2;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button btn;
    int i = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(id.button1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Click button 3-4 times and there will be natification and
                // click one of them

                notificationforChat("Message" + i,"sender" + i,i);
                //notificationforChat("sender" + i, "Message" + i, i);
                i++;
            }
        });

    }

    public void notificationforChat(String message, String sender,int notificationID) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("key", message);

        NotificationManager notifManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(this.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        int uniqueInteger = notificationID;// create a unique Integer
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

        NotificationCompat2.Builder mNotification = new NotificationCompat2.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(icon).setContentTitle(sender)
                .setContentIntent(getPendingIntent(bundle, uniqueInteger));

        mNotification.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS
                | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
        mNotification.setAutoCancel(true);
        notifManager.notify(uniqueInteger, mNotification.build());
    }

    private PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Bundle bundle, int rc) {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserChatActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        return PendingIntent.getActivity(this, rc, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
}
```

Then on the userChatActivity,

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class UserChatActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Intent intent = getIntent();        
        String key = intent.getStringExtra("key");      

        Log.v("notifica",key);

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how can I get the id of the notification on notification clicks. ?? How will it recognise the id now from the ArrayList?

Comment: How it will be get that which notification is clicked???

i. suppose there are two notifications. One is from user A and other is from user B. How will one get that which one is clicked????

Comment: Yu can changeyour method parameters => public void notificationforChat(CharSequence message, String toJid,
            int notificationID,String UserName)

Comment: You are not at all getting my point dear.
When a notification arrives ( its value is saved in bundle- jid value ) based upon the jid value it opens the new activity.
Now if another notification arrives and the old one is still dere then it simply updates the bundle so here when I click on any of the notifications I am redirected latest bundle value page.
Now please help me in this. How to get which notification is clicked on the other activity where it gets the value from the bundle

Comment: Did i misunderstand your question ?

Comment: Hi talhakosen. Thanks for the reply. It is not working. Actually What key would I get in the User Chat Activity, this is the major problem here

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the latest one is always what would be opened, is this not what you wanted?

Would you rather there be 2 separate notifications in the case you described? One for :A and one for :B ?